# Send multiple pdf's in an e-mail with Yii ePDF

Tags: php, pdf, yii

I am genereating pdf documents with a voucher for a reservation. Now the point is that a customer can book a room for multiple persons, so there should be two vouchers so the customer is not dependent on a single voucher.

I am using Yii's ePDF extension which uses mpdf and html2pdf. This is my code to generate a single pdf:

```
//foreach voucher generate a pdf
    foreach($rhrs as $rhr) {
                $this->generatePDF($reservation, $rhr);
            }
```

The generate pdf function:

```
private function generatePDF($reservation, $rhr)
{

    $pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('','', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $this->renderPartial('voucher', array(
            'rhr'=>$rhr,
            'reservation'=>$reservation
        ), true) );

    $this->sendMailWithPDF($pdf, $reservation);
}
```

The sendmailWithPDF function:

```
private function sendMailWithPDF($pdf, $reservation)
    {

        $content = $pdf->Output('', 'S');

        $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
        $mailto = $reservation->emailaddress;
             ....

            $is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
```

The problem is that this sends multiple e-mails with one pdf. I am trying to send one e-mail with multiple pdf's. I was thinking of building an array but at first I wanted to ask you guys, so what are your opinions on how to handle this properly?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: For multiple attachments, you just need multiple content sections, do you not? How is your email content formatted currently? There's just a blank string in your code??

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would decouple your `generatePDF()` function from the `sendMailWithPDF()` so that you can call them both independently.  Technically there's no reason why you need to send an email just to generate a PDF.

If instead your `generatePDF()` function simply returned the PDF object, you could create an array of them that could then be passed in to your `sendMailWithPDF()` function.

Something like this:

```
//foreach voucher generate a pdf
$generatedPDFs = array();
foreach($rhrs as $rhr) {
        $generatedPDFs[] = $this->generatePDF($reservation, $rhr);
}
// Call the mail function outside of the pdf generator, but pass in the array instead
$this->sendMailWithPDF($generatedPDFs, $reservation);


private function generatePDF($reservation, $rhr)
{

    $pdf = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf('','', 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'P');
    $pdf->WriteHTML( $this->renderPartial('voucher', array(
            'rhr'=>$rhr,
            'reservation'=>$reservation
        ), true) );

    return $pdf;
}


private function sendMailWithPDF($pdf, $reservation)
{

    //Update this section to handle $pdf being an array
    $content = $pdf->Output('', 'S');

    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $mailto = $reservation->emailaddress;
    ....

    $is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header);
}
```

Now the code may not work exactly as I've written it based on you system, but you should get an idea of what I mean by decoupling your functions to add flexibility.